# Redirect static to dynamic url using htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

In my case I need to this the other way around, I have more than 1000 links like this `www.domain.com/msg/98212.html` and I have to redirect them to new dynamic generated page like `www.domain.com/msg/view.php?id=98212`

The id or `98212.html` is different from file to file.

Any easy way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
RewriteRule ^msg/([0-9]+).html msg/view.php?id=$1 [L]
```

Make it `[R,L]` if you want the new URL to show in the user's browser.

Comment: Very nice, thank you, one more thing, I actually have a hash # in my links, www.domain.com/msg/98212#123.html.
How to implement that inside the htaccess file, because if I put it there as it is (#) it will generate false links.

Comment: Solved it by adding NE to [R,L]. Thank you for this very fast solution.

Comment: Sorry just saw this - glad it worked for you :) Please accept the answer if you're satisfied with it.

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteRule /msg/[0-9]+).html /msg/view.php?id=$1
```